# how to correctly use getDisplayMedia on peer js?

Tags: javascript, peerjs

hello recently I've been creating a video system called that is working super well here the code I'm using: Html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Delta Meet</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 class="title">Delta Meet</h1>
        <p id="notification" hidden></p>
        <div class="entry-modal" id="entry-modal">
            <p>Create or Join Meeting</p>
            <input id="room-input" class="room-input" placeholder="Enter Room ID">
            <div>
                <button onclick="createRoom()">Create Room</button>
                <button onclick="joinRoom()">Join Room</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="meet-area">
            <!-- Remote Video Element-->
            <video id="remote-video"></video>

            <!-- Local Video Element-->
            <video id="local-video"></video>
        </div>
        <br><br><br>
    </body>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/peerjs@1.3.1/dist/peerjs.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

and here the js:

```
const PRE = "DELTA"
const SUF = "MEET"
var room_id;
var getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia;
var local_stream;
function createRoom(){
    console.log("Creating Room")
    let room = document.getElementById("room-input").value;
    if(room == " " || room == "")   {
        alert("Please enter room number")
        return;
    }
    room_id = PRE+room+SUF;
    let peer = new Peer(room_id)
    peer.on('open', (id)=>{
        console.log("Peer Connected with ID: ", id)
        hideModal()
        getUserMedia({video: true, audio: true}, (stream)=>{
            local_stream = stream;
            setLocalStream(local_stream)
        },(err)=>{
            console.log(err)
        })
        notify("Waiting for peer to join.")
    })
    peer.on('call',(call)=>{
        call.answer(local_stream);
        call.on('stream',(stream)=>{
            setRemoteStream(stream)
        })
    })
}

function setLocalStream(stream){
    
    let video = document.getElementById("local-video");
    video.srcObject = stream;
    video.muted = true;
    video.play();
}
function setRemoteStream(stream){
   
    let video = document.getElementById("remote-video");
    video.srcObject = stream;
    video.play();
}

function hideModal(){
    document.getElementById("entry-modal").hidden = true
}

function notify(msg){
    let notification = document.getElementById("notification")
    notification.innerHTML = msg
    notification.hidden = false
    setTimeout(()=>{
        notification.hidden = true;
    }, 3000)
}

function joinRoom(){
    console.log("Joining Room")
    let room = document.getElementById("room-input").value;
    if(room == " " || room == "")   {
        alert("Please enter room number")
        return;
    }
    room_id = PRE+room+SUF;
    hideModal()
    let peer = new Peer()
    peer.on('open', (id)=>{
        console.log("Connected with Id: "+id)
        getUserMedia({video: true, audio: true}, (stream)=>{
            local_stream = stream;
            setLocalStream(local_stream)
            notify("Joining peer")
            let call = peer.call(room_id, stream)
            call.on('stream', (stream)=>{
                setRemoteStream(stream);
            })
        }, (err)=>{
            console.log(err)
        })

    })
}
```

so far so good, so I decided to create a button for the user to be able to share the screen:

```
<button id="start">Start Capture</button>&nbsp;<button id="stop">Stop Capture</button>
```

then I went there and created a script:

```
async function startCapture() {
 

  try {
    videoElem.srcObject = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia(displayMediaOptions);
    dumpOptionsInfo();
  } catch(err) {
    console.error("Error: " + err);
  }
}
function stopCapture(evt) {
  let tracks = videoElem.srcObject.getTracks();

  tracks.forEach(track => track.stop());
  videoElem.srcObject = null;
}
function dumpOptionsInfo() {
  const videoTrack = videoElem.srcObject.getVideoTracks()[0];

  console.info("Track settings:");
  console.info(JSON.stringify(videoTrack.getSettings(), null, 2));
  console.info("Track constraints:");
  console.info(JSON.stringify(videoTrack.getConstraints(), null, 2));
}const videoElem = document.getElementById("local-video");
const logElem = document.getElementById("log");
const startElem = document.getElementById("start");
const stopElem = document.getElementById("stop");

// Options for getDisplayMedia()

var displayMediaOptions = {
  video: {
    cursor: "always"
  },
  audio: false
};

// Set event listeners for the start and stop buttons
startElem.addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
  startCapture();
}, false);

stopElem.addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
  stopCapture();
}, false);
```

it works just right for me because for the other user it doesn't appear at all. What did I do wrong?